# CSS Code of div.card.signin-card.clearfix of Gmail login page

Tags: html, css, gmail

May I ask what is the css code of div.card.signin-card.clearfix of gmail login page. I am just a beginner to CSS. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking the help of the inspect element.

```
  .clearfix 
   {
      zoom:1
   }
  .signin-card {
      width: 274px;
      padding: 40px 40px;
   } 
   .card 
   {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
   }
```